# How to limit the body can not be drag out in Framework7?

Tags: html, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I am using `Framework7` for hybird development.

and In my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<title>My App</title>
<!-- Path to Framework7 Library CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/framework7.ios.min.css">
<!-- Path to your custom app styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-app.css">
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

The effect on my simulator:

I want the body is fixed, can not be drag, how to fix the position, if drag can not can not let the whole view move up or down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to you config.xml

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```